# reduce duplication in rails mvc/form/views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, duplicates, erb

Can upload images & videos independently (only want one at a time but with choice to be either file type) There is duplication in each view file for image and video as well as in Model (initially to test upload works for both file types) Want to encapsulate in to one element/tag/file/type whatever is correct, tried using 'attachment' to encapsulate both, this did not work and specific video_tag & image_tag seem necessary (please correct me if not the case) Have been spiking.

Any help/ideas how to refactor the duplication appreciated?

Contacts model:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: {thumb: "300x300>"}, border:{thumb: "1px solid #ddd"}

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpg"] }

  has_attached_file :video, styles: { :medium => { :geometry => "300x300>", :format => 'mov', :time => 10 }
      }, :processors => [:transcoder]

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, { content_type: ["video/mpeg", "video/mov", "video/wmv", "video/mp4", "video/qt", "video/mng", "video/avi"] }
```

new.erb  (note the duplication for file_field and have two tags image/video when wanting to encapsulate as one)

```
<div class="polaroid" >
    <div class="container">
        <div>
          <%= f.file_field :image %>
          <%= image_tag(:image_url) %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.file_field :video %>
          <%= video_tag(:video_url) %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />

<%= f.submit %>
```

show.erb (duplicated lines dealing with image and email)

```
<p><%= image_tag @contact.image.url(:thumb) %></p>
<p><%= video_tag @contact.video.url(:medium), :width=>300, :controls => true, :autoplay => true, :loop => true, :class=>"work"  %></p>
```

index.erb (again duplicated link_to for both tags)

```
  <div class="polaroid" >
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to image_tag(contact2.image.url(:thumb), :class=> "work" ), contact_path(contact2) %>
      <%= link_to video_tag(contact2.video.url(:medium), :size => "250x250", :autoplay => true, :loop => true, :class=>"work" ), contact_path(contact2) %>
        <h3><%=contact2.firstname%> <%=contact2.surname%></h3>
```

Comment: My advice would be to stop trying to deduplicate that what is not identical: your definition of a video differs from that of an image (filetypes, postprocessing, etc). Often a little duplication is better than the wrong  abstraction.

Comment: zwippie tks. For the new.erb wanting one upload (which can be either image or video) do you know how you would implement a choice selection here? Assume an if statement but have had no luck writing it. The if would have to be implemented through each erb file to show either of the files that had been uploaded.